# Mysql join where value or null

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a table PROD

```
ID    NAME
1     Apple
2     Banana
```

And the relative table PRICES , with global prices (ID_USER is Null) 
or per-user prices (ID_USER)

```
PROD_ID    USER_ID   PRICE
1          null      10
1          5         8
```

Now, i need a query that finds all products and the relative prices,

the catch is that i'm trying to retrieve the user price only if there is one, else retrieve the global price

```
SELECT PROD.* , PRICES.* FROM PROD
LEFT JOIN PRICES ON PROD.ID_PROD = PRICES.ID_PROD 
WHERE PRICES.USER_ID IS NULL OR PRICES.USER_ID = 5
```

This query returns 2 rows (the prod joined with the 2 prices)

Is there a way to retrieve the exact price for the product in just one query ?

thanks !!

EDIT: In the join i need the per-user price row (the last one) only if the row exists , else i need to retrieve the row with the global price,  is that possible ?

Comment: What is the exact price?

Comment: Please elaborate the question much more as it is not clear the requirement.

Comment: if a user is logged in, i'm fetching the prices with USER_ID = (logged user id) ,  but some products may not have the price per-user, so i need to fetch the price with the USER_ID = NULL

Comment: Oh, that's easy. See COALESCE()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  prod.*,
  COALESCE(p_user, p_default) As Price
FROM
  Prod INNER JOIN (SELECT
                     PROD_ID,
                     MAX(CASE WHEN USER_ID=5 THEN Price END) p_user,
                     MAX(CASE WHEN USER_ID IS NULL THEN Price END) p_default
                   FROM
                     Prices
                   GROUP
                     BY PROD_ID) m_uid
  ON Prod.ID = m_uid.Prod_ID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27e1a/2).